# Who is voicing Hattori in Gintama The Final?

Tags: gintama, voice-acting

As far as I know, the original voice actor of Hattori Zenzou has died, so who is his voice actor in *Gintama The Final*, and who is going to be in the 2 episodes of *The Semi-final*?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [answer in Yahoo Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12237128492?query=%E9%8A%80%E9%AD%82%20%E6%9C%8D%E9%83%A8%E5%85%A8%E8%94%B5), the movie pamphlet has Toshiyuki Morikawa listed as Hattori's character voice. The [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A3%AE%E5%B7%9D%E6%99%BA%E4%B9%8B) also lists him as Hattori. He also plays as Isaburo Sasaki in the same series. Note that Morikawa also replaced Keiji Fujiwara as Hiroshi in Crayon Shin-chan, so this was a natural choice.